# How to know where is the boot.img partition

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, boot

I would like to modify my init.rc  file for get  init.d support  trough the the boot.img file. As I know is the touchy action I've got several procedure but anyone referenced with I can note on my device.

```
1|root@nexbox_a95x:/ # cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 253        0     512000 zram0
 179        0    7634944 mmcblk0
 179        1       4096 mmcblk0p1
 179        2      65536 mmcblk0p2
 179        3     524288 mmcblk0p3
 179        4       8192 mmcblk0p4
 179        5      32768 mmcblk0p5
 179        6      32768 mmcblk0p6
 179        7       8192 mmcblk0p7
 179        8       8192 mmcblk0p8
 179        9      32768 mmcblk0p9
 179       10      32768 mmcblk0p10
 179       11     524288 mmcblk0p11
 179       12      32768 mmcblk0p12
 179       13    1048576 mmcblk0p13
 179       14    5148672 mmcblk0p14
 179       96        512 mmcblk0rpmb
 179       64       4096 mmcblk0boot1
 179       32       4096 mmcblk0boot0
root@nexbox_a95x:/ # cat /proc/mtd                                             
dev:    size   erasesize  name
root@nexbox_a95x:/ # ls -l /dev/block/platform/d0074000.emmc/by-num/           
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p1 -> /dev/block/bootloader
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p10 -> /dev/block/misc
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p11 -> /dev/block/instaboot
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p12 -> /dev/block/boot
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p13 -> /dev/block/system
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p14 -> /dev/block/data
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p2 -> /dev/block/reserved
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p3 -> /dev/block/cache
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p4 -> /dev/block/env
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p5 -> /dev/block/logo
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p6 -> /dev/block/recovery
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p7 -> /dev/block/rsv
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p8 -> /dev/block/tee
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2015-01-01 01:00 p9 -> /dev/block/crypt
```

Someone could tell me where is the boot.img partition is this shell result?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `/dev/block/boot`?

Comment: @AndyYan `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot`

Comment: @iBug I mean from the info he posted. Not every device have `bootdevice`  exactly as it is. Let OP explore that.

Comment: Hi,  who is the OP?

Comment: OP = original poster = you.

Comment: @Andy Chicken and eggs How to choice between bootloader, instaboot, and boot partition